# Why StreamWriter.Flush() gives ObjectDisposedExeption here?

Tags: c#, multithreading, streamwriter

This is sort of educational example. Trying to make output.txt like

> counter + 0
>
> counter + 1

etc. by writing each line by different thread.

```
using (StreamWriter output = File.CreateText("output.txt"))
{
    object block = new object();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Action<object> writeFunction = delegate (object obj) 
        {
            lock (block)
            {
                int counter = (int) obj;
                output.WriteLine("counter + " + counter);
                //output.Flush(); 
            }
        };

        Thread newThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(writeFunction));
        newThread.Start(i);
    }
}
```

The commented output.Flush() causes System.ObjectDisposedException "Access to closed file is not possible".

Comment: Please explain what "make it work" means. What is your expectations?

Comment: So it would produce output.txt with "Counter + 1" to "Counter + 9" lines. Each written by different thread.

Comment: Your threads are running async. So this code will continue to execute, whe you exit the using statement the dispose is called.

Comment: Sorry, should also add. I would not write a multi thread like this, you will clash on file locking. Better to have a single background thread feeding off a queue and doing the writing.

Comment: @PaulThomas, thanks, now I see.